# How do I prevent a BinaryFormatter Deserialize method from hanging?

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

The code below hangs on the last statement.  I have no idea what to look for to fix.

```
string tstName = "c:\\tmp\\tmp.tst";
BinaryWriter out = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(tstName)); 
BinaryFormatter outformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
outformatter.Serialize(out.BaseStream, myClass);
out.Close();

BinaryReader inn = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(tstName));
BinaryFormatter informatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MyClass pTest = 
    (MyClass)informatter.Deserialize(inn.BaseStream);
```

If it is of any help, the file 'tmp.tst' contains 148 MB after the serialization.

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve] and so does not have enough information for an answer.  What I would do is to debug using visual studio.  Possibly some exception is getting thrown inside `Deserialize()` which isn't getting handled properly; if you stop on first-chance exceptions you will be able to track it down.  Or if `Deserialize()` really is hanging you can stop execution and see where it is happening.  Running under a profiler might help also.

Comment: Incidentally [BinaryFormatter is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) as of .NET 5 and will be entirely removed as of .NET 9.  See [BinaryFormatter Obsoletion Strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete).  So you should be looking to move away from BinaryFormatter rather than to fix problems with it.

Comment: Or maybe there is an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: To quote the [security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide#binaryformatter-security-vulnerabilities): *"The `Deserialize` method can be used as a vector for attackers to perform DoS attacks against consuming apps. These attacks might render the app unresponsive..."*. Your object may have accidentally triggered the bug/vulnerability in `BinaryFormatter`